# Marquee text pass over the sidenav

Tags: html, css

I have a marquee text and I have a right side navigation bar. The problem is, When the text moves to the right it goes under the sidenav and I cannot see it. I want to know how to style my text to pass over the sidenav not going under it. I mean, I want to make my text visible in all of the way not going and disappearing under side navigation.
The code:
footer.html:

```
<footer class="w3-container">
    <marquee direction="right">
        <ul>
            <li>طراح گرافیک از این متن به عنوان عنصری از ترکیب بندی برای پر کردن صفحه و ارایه اولیه شکل ظاهری و کلی طرح سفارش گرفته شده استفاده می نماید.</li>
            <li>طراحی شده توسط محسن نیروزاد</li>
        </ul>
    </marquee>
</footer>
```

engineers.php:

```
<div data-ng-include="'variables/footer.html'"></div>
```

app.css:

```
marquee {
    width: calc(33.33% + 150px);
}
footer marquee ul {
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: I added the code...

Comment: Why you want width to be limited?

Comment: because the one wanted me to make him this page told me. He wanted the text start moving after two third section of the page.

Comment: Try the flowing change as I've mentioned in the answer

Comment: set `z-index` of the sidebar to `1` and of the marquee to `2` ? higher value means the element is shown above elements with lower `z-index`.

Comment: @SimonHänisch , I did it before but It doesn't work properly:
`marquee{z-index:2 !important}nav{z-index:1 !important}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use the z-index property.

First, position both elements using `position: relative;`, or any other variant of `position:`. Then, use `z-index:` to change how high up each element is. Give the lower element (the sidebar) a `z-index: 1;` property, and the higher element (the marquee) a `z-index: 2;` property. You can use any numbers, so long as the lower item has a lower number.

Comment: Awesome! The problem solved!
`marquee {
    z-index: 2 !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
nav {
    z-index: 1 !important;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change your CSS from:-

```
marquee{width:100%;}
```

Comment: can you provide a Js fiddle??

Comment: You can check it online: http://sarabonstudio.ir/index.php?v=desktopview
Wait for the footer to move...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a z-index in the css like: `z-index: 10;`